# Excel Crashes when VBA runs

Tags: vba, excel, crash

This one is driving me crazy, since i've been building it for a while. 
After having debugged the code part by part, when I run it as a whole my Excel Spreadsheet crashes. I think it's because I have too many loops in eachother.. but you tell me. I don't know how to break up the Sub without loosing positional values:

```
Sub Prop()

Dim ptbl As ListObject
Set ptbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Process")
Dim p As Range
Set p = ptbl.ListColumns("Operation").Range
Dim htbl As ListObject
Set htbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("Hourly")
Dim mtbl As ListObject
Set mtbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Materials")
Dim m As Range
Set m = mtbl.ListColumns("Type").Range

'define process data table
Dim numOp As Range
Set numOp = ptbl.ListColumns("Number of Operators Required").Range
Dim ppHr As Range
Set ppHr = ptbl.ListColumns("Parts per Hour @ 85% Eff.").Range
Dim stpT As Range
Set stpT = ptbl.ListColumns("Set Up Time: Hours").Range
Dim scrpR As Range
Set scrpR = ptbl.ListColumns("Scrap Rate %").Range

'define process fillout tables
Dim lotz As Range      'lot size
Dim labr As Range      'labor
Dim mach As Range      'machine am.
Dim setp As Range      'setup
Dim qual As Range      'quality
Dim main As Range      'maintenance
Dim scrp As Range      'scrap
Dim totl As Range      'total

'define hourly table
Dim hrLa As Double
Dim hrMA As Double
Dim hrSe As Double
Dim hrQL As Double
Dim hrML As Double

'empty out all the cells of the process tables
For cle = 1 To 20
    Sheet1.Range("Process" & cle).ClearContents
Next cle


For pr = 2 To p.Rows.Count Step 1

Dim ptn As Range
Set ptn = Sheet1.Range("Process" & pr - 1)

If p.Rows(pr).Value <> "" Then
    If p.Rows(pr).Value <> "Please Choose Operation" Then
        'Set the process table to have the part name
            ptn(1, 1) = p.Rows(pr).Value
            ptn(1, 5) = "Part Name:"
            ptn(1, 6) = ptbl.ListColumns("Part Name Ref.").Range.Rows(pr).Value
            ptn(1, 8) = "Parts per Hour @ 85% Eff."
            ptn(2, 8) = ppHr.Rows(pr).Value
            ptn(2, 1) = "Lot Size:"
            ptn(3, 2) = "Costs"
            ptn(3, 8) = "Hourly Rate"
            ptn(4, 1) = htbl.Range(2, 1).Value
            ptn(5, 1) = htbl.Range(3, 1).Value
            ptn(6, 1) = htbl.Range(4, 1).Value
            ptn(7, 1) = htbl.Range(5, 1).Value
            ptn(8, 1) = htbl.Range(6, 1).Value
            ptn(9, 1) = "Scrap Cost:"
            ptn(10, 1) = "Total Cost:"

            'Calculation for appropriate operations hourly rate
            For r = 2 To htbl.Range.Columns.Count
                If p.Rows(pr).Value = htbl.HeaderRowRange.Columns(r).Value Then
                    hrLa = htbl.Range(2, r).Value
                    ptn(4, 8) = hrLa
                    hrMA = htbl.Range(3, r).Value
                    ptn(5, 8) = hrMA
                    hrSe = htbl.Range(4, r).Value
                    ptn(6, 8) = hrSe
                    hrQL = htbl.Range(5, r).Value
                    ptn(7, 8) = hrQL
                    hrML = htbl.Range(6, r).Value
                    ptn(8, 8) = hrML
                End If
            Next r

            Dim c As Integer
            'Calculation for each cell's functions
            For c = 2 To 7
                'defining row name for each lot size column (c)
                    Set lotz = ptn(2, c)
                    Set labr = ptn(4, c)
                    Set mach = ptn(5, c)
                    Set setp = ptn(6, c)
                    Set qual = ptn(7, c)
                    Set main = ptn(8, c)
                    Set scrp = ptn(9, c)
                    Set totl = ptn(10, c)

                    'lotsize calls to estimator input
                        lotz = Sheet1.Range("Header")(5, c + 1)
                    'labor cost is pph over hourly rate
                        labr = (numOp.Rows(pr).Value * ppHr.Rows(pr).Value) / hrLa
                    'machine cost is pph over hrly rate machine
                        mach = ppHr.Rows(pr).Value / hrMA
                    'setup cost is hrly setup over lotsize
                        setp = (stpT.Rows(pr).Value * hrSe) / lotz
                    'quality cost is hrly qual over lotsize
                        qual = ((ptbl.Range(pr, 10).Value / 60) * ptbl.Range(pr, 11).Value) * hrQL / lotz
                    'maintenance is hrly maint. over lotsize
                        main = (ptbl.ListColumns("Maintenance per Shift: Minutes").Range.Rows(pr).Value / 60) * hrML / lotz
                    'total cost per part
                        totl = labr + mach + setp + qual + main + scrp

                        'Calculation for appropriate materials rate
                        For mt = 2 To m.Rows.Count - 1
                            Dim mtn As Range
                            Set mtn = Sheet1.Range("Materials" & mt - 1)

                            Dim lastMC As Double
                            Dim MCost As Double

                            If mtbl.ListColumns("Part Name").Range.Rows(mt).Value = ptbl.ListColumns("Part Name Ref.").Range.Rows(pr).Value Then
                                'makinig sure there is a last material cost
                                If mt - 2 > 0 Then
                                lastMC = Sheet1.Range("Materials" & mt - 2)(9, c).Value
                                Else: lastMC = 0
                                End If

                                MCost = mtn(9, c).Value
                            End If
                        Next mt

                    'scrap rate cost is material cost plus the process cost of scrap per part over the lot size
                        scrp = ((lastMC + MCost + labr + mach + setp + qual + main) * (scrpR.Rows(pr).Value * lotz)) / (lotz - (scrpR.Rows(pr).Value) * lotz)
            Next c

    End If
End If
Next pr

End Sub
```

If you have any feedback at all, other then just being mean, I'd love to hear it.
Thanks!

Comment: Any error messages?  Excel just crashes, or becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Without the data this is quite difficult to say. My gut says that it may have something to do with the amount of read/write operations this code has to do on the actual document itself.

Comment: If you really want to dig into it, you can put your code in sections, with a msgbox in each section. `Msgbox "Starting Section 1"` or something. When you fail to see the msgbox, you know which section of code is causing the issues, which can help us help you.

Comment: You can "break up" a monster macro by creating a `Main` which calls sub routines for each action, and let your sub routines call functions to calculate values which are voluminous (in code) to program or used repetitively. Use arguments with your subs and functions to supply values needed by them (better than declaring global variables for the same purpose). Values which are used everywhere would be declared in the Main and passed to the sub which pass them to the functions. Most values, you will find, can be declared in the subs and passed to the functions from there, not needed in the Main.

Comment: It seems like you have created a ListObject for each column of your worksheet and then refer to each table's cells by `Rows(n)`. I am surprised that it works (and perhaps it doesn't, causing the crash). My first question is whether you need any tables at all. You might use Enums to name your columns. In this way 80% of your code would be superfluous.

Comment: I'd suggest disabling automatic calculations (`Application.Calculation = xlManual`) at the beginning of your macro and see if that helps. I suspect with all the changes you're making to the worksheets, it's continually recalculating.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for responding so quickly, I really appreciate it and will give these recommendations a whirl as soon as I'm back at work. Tim, excel just crashes after the spinning spiral flashes between that and my mouse pointer.. Which is why I suspect it's a loop related issue. There is no error or anything, windows just gives me the support popup and asks if I want it try and recover the spreadsheet. SilentRevolution, I'm not sure what you mean by that, unfortunately I can't upload the actual document since it's a segment of my company's quoting spreadsheet.

Comment: K. Davis, thanks for the tip, that's actually my go to debugging method! As far as I'm concerned theres nothing really wrong with the code, since I've already debugged it in the way you describe. Variatus, this is actually a sub of a main I wrote. The main works perfectly, my issue is that because I'm relatively new to coding I'm not that good at simplifying my code yet.. I'll have a go at it though, it's a good tip. I left the table and columns referenced in each range since I'm worries that if I give this back to my boss, he's going to physically move tables and columns around..

Comment: .. It's my way of trying to make the macro fool proof since he doesn't know vba! I'm going to look into using Enums as you say, maybe I can find a way around this. Thanks PeterT for that tip, that's the first I'm going to try out in the morning!